# print in first column based on line number correct sequence

Tags: awk

I have a file, file1, with following values

```
50
43
43
39
38
```

I have defined a constant parameter "framei=218" and I want to obtain the following output, file2

```
218   50
218.5 43
219   43
219.5 39
220   38
```

will be something like the following

```
awk '{print NR*'$framei' " " $s}' file1 > file2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The formula needs to be a bit more complex:

```
awk '{print (NR-1)/2+'$framei' " " $s}'
```

Or, if you initialize `$framei` to 217.5:

```
awk '{print NR/2+'$framei' " " $s}'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '{print '$framei'+NR/2-0.5 " " $s}' file1 > file2
```

Answer (score 0):

Done by Below command

```
awk 'BEGIN{sum=218}NR>1{sum=sum+0.5}{print sum,$1}' file
```

output

```
218 50
218.5 43
219 43
219.5 39
220 38
```

Python

```
#!/usr/bin/python
sum=218
k=open('file','r')
l=k.readlines()
print len(l)
for i in range(0,len(l),1):
    print sum,l[i].strip()
    sum=sum+0.5
```

output

```
218 50
218.5 43
219 43
219.5 39
220 38
```